# How to handle a notification when app is not active?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, wns

I am doing push notifications in Windows 10 universal using C# and XAML. Everything is working perfectly. When I receive a notification and the app is running I use this function to do something when the notification comes in.

```
private async void Channel_PushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    //do something in reaction to the notification
}
```

But when the app is in the background I get a toast notification in the form of a badge. When I click that the app opens to the last page it was on. However what I want to do is when the badge is clicked I want to be able to call a function in my code. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If your app is not running in the front, it will be activated and you can put your code in the `OnActivated` event handler.

Depending on the type of notification you'll use, there are small differences in handling, possible types are:

- Foreground activation from a toast notification using Windows 10
  adaptive template
- Background activation from a toast notification
  using Windows 10 adaptive template
- Legacy: Foreground activation
  from a toast notification using legacy template.

*This is the code you'll be using for foreground activation with the Windows 10 toast templates (most used one):*

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    // TODO: Initialize root frame just like in OnLaunched

    // Handle toast activation
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
    {
        var toastArgs = args as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;

        // your code
    }

    // TODO: Handle other types of activation
}
```

You can follow this [quickstart for sending and handling activations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/#handling-activation) for a sample of each type. The quickstart also uses a NuGet package to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add windows runtime component in your project to handle and process notification in background while your app is closed. Here is the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background,) for handling different kind of triggers using windows runtime component.

[here is the video tutorial by lynda for the same](https://www.lynda.com/Windows-tutorials/Developing-UWP-Apps-9-Background-Tasks/645024-2.html)